# Kendo Multiselect with composite dataTextField

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on the following:

My Multiselect:

```
 @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.PAYMENT_METHOD).BindTo(paymentMethods).DataTextField("TITLE").DataValueField("CODE")
```

The dataSource looks like this:

```
CODE     TITLE
  1       abc
  2       def
```

Is it possible to have composite `DataTextField` , specifically like: `1 - abc, 2 - def, etc.`, i.e `"CODE" - "TITLE"`?

I know I could create a select list and define the format of textfield, but maybe there is another way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify a template for the display item (you would probably want to take the text field out then):

```
 @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.PAYMENT_METHOD)
              .BindTo(paymentMethods)
              //.DataTextField("TITLE")
              .DataValueField("CODE")
              .ItemTemplate("#= CODE# #=' - '# #= TITLE#")
```

Here's the link to the [`ItemTemplate` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-itemTemplate) and the link to the general [`template` methods](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-template).

Comment: Thanks! ItemTemplate("#= CODE# #=' - '# #= TITLE#").TagTemplate("#= CODE# #=' - '# #= TITLE#") works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add a search param to your datasource class that doesn't need to be mapped to your database. But evaluates the instance of the object and creates this composite field you can use to search. I have done this for times when searches are needed on FirstName and LastName.

```
public class YourObjectModel 
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string SearchTerm => $"{Code}{Title}"
}
```

Then set .dataTextField("SearchTerm") and there you go.